# Mark Indicator using R data table

Tags: r

I have a dataset where I want to carry out the following manipulation, but I am not able to find the optimal solution.

```
Name    Date    Paid    Outstanding Mark as Follows    Close Indicator
A   2000    100 200             Open         0
A   2001    224 100             Open         0
A   2002    348 400             Open         0
A   2003    472 0      First Time it Closes      1
A   2004    596 196             Reopens     -1
B   2004    720 200             Open         0
B   2005    844 200             Open         0
B   2006    968 0      First Time it Closes      1
B   2007    968 0               Closes       0
C   2000    1092    200             Open         0
C   2001    1216    1200                Open         0
B   2008    1340    1200               Reopens      -1
B   2010    1464    100             Open         0
B   2011    1588    0              Closes        1
A   2016    1712    0              Closes        1
D   2009    1836    60              Open         0
D   2010    1896    0              Closes        1
D   2016    1900    0              Closes        0
```

What I want to be able I want to replicate the Close indicator column. these are transaction cumulative amounts. My logic is for name, if the payment is made and there is no Outstanding then I want to mark it a 1, indicating close. If however in the future this case opens, then I want to mark -1 and 1 again when it closes. So A closes in 2003 and then reopens in 2004 and closes back in 2016.

For D the case closes in 2010, but the payment changes in 2016 so although in theory this also get a reopen flag, given it closes back again at the same time I want to be able to deal with this situation as well.

What would be the best way of doing this in R Data table be?

Comment: Please use the `dput()` function in R to generate the R code to create your test data. For example, if your data frame is called `df`, execute `dput(df)` into the R console and then copy and paste the function's output at the start of this question. This will make it much easier for people to help you with your question!

Answer (score 0):

The logic is, for each Name

- If Outstanding is zero when it was previously non-zero, close_indicator
  is 1
- If Outstanding is non-zero when it was previously zero,
  close_indicator is -1
- Otherwise Outstanding hasn't changed,
  close_indicator is 0

For each Name, this can be expressed as `(Outstanding == 0) - (lag(Outstanding) == 0)`. This is getting the difference between two logicals which get coerced into 0 or 1.

So all we have to do is group by Name, sort by Date and use that formula.

```
library('tidyverse')
df <- tribble(
  ~Name, ~Date, ~Outstanding,
    "A", 2000L,         200L,
    "A", 2001L,         100L,
    "A", 2002L,         400L,
    "A", 2003L,           0L,
    "A", 2004L,         196L,
    "B", 2004L,         200L,
    "B", 2005L,         200L,
    "B", 2006L,           0L,
    "B", 2007L,           0L,
    "C", 2000L,         200L,
    "C", 2001L,        1200L,
    "B", 2008L,        1200L,
    "B", 2010L,         100L,
    "B", 2011L,           0L,
    "A", 2016L,           0L,
    "D", 2009L,          60L,
    "D", 2010L,           0L,
    "D", 2016L,           0L
)

df %>%
  rowid_to_column %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  arrange(Date) %>%
  mutate(close_indicator = (Outstanding == 0) - (lag(Outstanding) == 0)) %>%
  replace_na(list(close_indicator = 0)) %>%
  arrange(rowid)
# # A tibble: 18 x 5
# # Groups:   Name [4]
#    rowid  Name  Date Outstanding close_indicator
#    <int> <chr> <int>       <int>           <dbl>
#  1     1     A  2000         200               0
#  2     2     A  2001         100               0
#  3     3     A  2002         400               0
#  4     4     A  2003           0               1
#  5     5     A  2004         196              -1
#  6     6     B  2004         200               0
#  7     7     B  2005         200               0
#  8     8     B  2006           0               1
#  9     9     B  2007           0               0
# 10    10     C  2000         200               0
# 11    11     C  2001        1200               0
# 12    12     B  2008        1200              -1
# 13    13     B  2010         100               0
# 14    14     B  2011           0               1
# 15    15     A  2016           0               1
# 16    16     D  2009          60               0
# 17    17     D  2010           0               1
# 18    18     D  2016           0               0
```

For `data.table`s, this can be done with

```
dt[, close_indicator := (Outstanding == 0) - (shift(Outstanding) == 0), by = Name]
dt[is.na(close_indicator), close_indicator := 0]
#     Name Date Outstanding close_indicator
#  1:    A 2000         200               0
#  2:    A 2001         100               0
#  3:    A 2002         400               0
#  4:    A 2003           0               1
#  5:    A 2004         196              -1
#  6:    B 2004         200               0
#  7:    B 2005         200               0
#  8:    B 2006           0               1
#  9:    B 2007           0               0
# 10:    C 2000         200               0
# 11:    C 2001        1200               0
# 12:    B 2008        1200              -1
# 13:    B 2010         100               0
# 14:    B 2011           0               1
# 15:    A 2016           0               1
# 16:    D 2009          60               0
# 17:    D 2010           0               1
# 18:    D 2016           0               0
```

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for the reply. I will try and follow this logic, it makes sense. I am currently working with data table so trying to replicate this there.

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`. I'm not sure I completely understand your criteria, but I think the example below should be enough to get you up and going. The primary function that should help you here is the [shift function in data table](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.10.4-2/topics/shift). Coupled with grouping operations (using `by = .(Name)` clause ) you can add in a column for the previous balance.

Once you have that column created, you can then use compound logic based on your criteria to add the flags you need on the relevant rows.

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(Name = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A","A", "A", "A", "B", "B","B", "B", "B"),
           Date = c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003),
           Outstanding = c(200, 100, 600 ,400, 0, 196, 200, 0, 500, 600, 0, 200, 0))

setkey(DT,Name,Date)

## Add a new column for previous outstanding balance
DT[,Prev_Outstanding := shift(Outstanding, n = 1L, fill = NA, type = "lag"), by = .(Name)]

DT[,CloseIndicator := 0] ## Pre-fill all rows with 0 initially
DT[Prev_Outstanding > 0 & Outstanding == 0, CloseIndicator := 1, by = .(Name)] ## Mark account closings
DT[Prev_Outstanding == 0 & Outstanding > 0, CloseIndicator := -1, by = .(Name)] ## Mark Account re-openings

print(DT)
```

Yields:

```
    Name Date Outstanding Prev_Outstanding CloseIndicator
 1:    A 2000         200               NA              0
 2:    A 2001         100              200              0
 3:    A 2002         600              100              0
 4:    A 2003         400              600              0
 5:    A 2004           0              400              1
 6:    A 2005         196                0             -1
 7:    A 2006         200              196              0
 8:    A 2007           0              200              1
 9:    B 2000         600               NA              0
10:    B 2001           0              600              1
11:    B 2002         200                0             -1
12:    B 2003           0              200              1
13:    B 2008         500                0             -1
```